# Proxy port configuration in lubuntu

Tags: networking, internet, proxy, wired

I recently installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (dual-boot with windows) and in the network settings there is not a port option to configure. In my place of work I use a wired connection with a http proxy with a port and fix IP and I need be able to use a configuration for this LAN and no proxy for wireless. Is there a way to configure this?

(I have no experience with Linux systems before.)

I'm using now Firefox which allows me to do this, but it does not work for chrome or the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the system wide proxy settings in `/etc/environment/`. Open this file as `sudo` and add the following lines, btw. the lines you need to setup your proxy settings:

```
http_proxy=http://your-ip-or-host:your-port/
HTTP_PROXY=http://your-ip-or-host:your-port/
https_proxy=http://your-ip-or-host:your-port/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://your-ip-or-host:your-port/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Set upper and lower case, because both are required by some applications.

This will set the proxy settings globally. In Firefox or other Browsers select `Use system proxy settings` in the **Network Settings**.

With this little `proxy.sh` script you can toggle the proxy settings:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# require root permissions to change /etc/environment/
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root";
  exit 1;
fi

# proxy configuration
proxy_host="myhost"
proxy_port=1234
ignored="localhost,127.0.0.1"

if [ "$1" == "on" ]; then
  # add proxy configuration to file
  printf "http_proxy=http://$proxy_host:$proxy_port/\n\
HTTP_PROXY=http://$proxy_host:$proxy_port/\n\
https_proxy=http://$proxy_host:$proxy_port/\n\
HTTPS_PROXY=http://$proxy_host:$proxy_port/\n\
no_proxy=\"$ignored\"\n\
NO_PROXY=\"$ignored\"\n" >> /etc/environment/
elif [ "$1" == "off" ]; then
  #remove proxy configuration from file
  grep -vE "(proxy|PROXY)" /etc/environment/ > /tmp/proxy.txt
  cat /tmp/proxy.txt > /etc/environment/
  rm /tmp/proxy.txt
else
  # print usage help
  echo "use \"proxy.sh on\" to enable proxy settings and \"proxy.sh off\" to disable it."
fi
```

Comment: And how can I undo this for when I need no proxy in a wireless connection? Is there a way I can write this in a script, and in another one the way to restore it? I need to change sometimes several times in a day between LAN and wireless.

Comment: You can just comment out the lines with `#` to disable the proxy settings

Comment: I updated my answer and added a little script to toggle the proxy settings. Hope the helps.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel. I have to change to "/etc/environment", instead of "/etc/environment/" as it should be a file, and not a directory. And after having it changed, do relogin to make it in effect